# Importing class from another script in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, importerror

I'm trying to import a class from another script so I can run the class when a button is clicked in tkinter.

The line of code I'm trying to run is:

```
from tkinter import *
import originalscript as desiredclass

variable = desiredclass()
```

When I try to run my code, the second line gives me an 'invalid syntax' error.

The two files are in the same folder and I've looked at other threads regarding this problem, but most of them suggest this as the solution, however, this line is not working for me, so I'm wondering what I am doing wrong/what I am missing?

The error code is:
Syntax Error: invalid syntax: filepath.py, line 2, pos 10
import script as class

Comment: Remove the `.py`

Comment: I removed the .py, but I am still getting an invalid syntax error.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to post a [mcve]. There's no way this line of code can throw a SyntaxError in python 3.

Comment: There are a few ways you might need to import. Sometimes if your script files are inside of a package they need the package name first. example: `import package_name.py_file_name as myscript`. Other times you can do `import py_file_name as my_script`. You might want to change your import by using one of the 2 examples I gave instead of using `from`. This is all assuming both of your files are in the same directory.

Comment: Please show the full, actual error message. There is no syntax in the lines of code you've provided.

Comment: I see that you added some more to your example import however we need to see the complete trackback error. That means all the other stuff that comes up also.

Comment: There are many issues that could be going on here. Can you please add how your files are set up in your main folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

from you update to your question it looks like you may be trying to import the file as a class. Instead of doing:

```
variable = desiredclass()
```

Try this:

```
variable = desiredclass.ClassNameInFile()
```

There are several ways you might wish to import your own files.

For example if your file structure looks like this:

```
--Workfolder
    --Main.py
    --other.py
```

You may want to import something like this.

```
import other
```

Or if you want only something specific from that file do:

```
from other import func_name
```

However if it is part of a package you sometimes need to specify the package name first.

So if your file structure is like this:

```
--Workfolder
    --MY_PACKAGE
      --Main.py
      --other.py
```

You may want to import like this:

```
import MY_PACKAGE.other
```

or for a specific function:

```
from MY_PACKAGE.other import func_name
```

Let me know if you have any questions.